# malloc(): invalid size (unsorted) on new unsigned char[<size>]

Tags: c++, malloc, valgrind

There are enormous amounts of memory-error related posts here on SO but none addresses my problem.

Consider this class (definition and declaration merged for an easy read):

```
#define SIZEMACRO(mem) *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(mem)
class StoredRecord {
  uint64_t idx;
  unsigned char* mem;
 public:
  ~StoredRecord() { 
    delete[] mem;
  }

  StoredRecord() : idx(0), mem(nullptr) {}

  StoredRecord(uint64_t _idx, unsigned char* _mem) : idx(_idx), mem(new unsigned char[SIZEMACRO(_mem)]) {
    memcpy(mem, _mem, SIZEMACRO(_mem));
  }

  static std::shared_ptr<StoredRecord> createShared(uint64_t _idx, unsigned char* _mem) {
    return std::make_shared<StoredRecord>(_idx, _mem);
  }

  // Some getter for idx and mem
};
```

It doesnt do much, takes the memory and uses `SIZEMACRO()` (which evaluates the first bytes as uint32_t and uses this as the size, works well) to determinate the size of the memory chunk, allocates the same size and copies it.

These `StoredRecord` are kept in an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<StoredRecord>> m_records` in another class.
No problem here whats-o-ever.
However, the code crashes when used as follows:

```
const uint32_t a = 1800;
const uint32_t b = 1900;
const uint32_t c = 2000;
unsigned char data1[a]; 
unsigned char data2[b];
unsigned char data3[c];
memset(data1, 0, a);
memset(data2, 0, b);
memset(data3, 0, c);
memcpy(data1, &a, sizeof(uint32_t));
memcpy(data2, &b, sizeof(uint32_t));
memcpy(data3, &c, sizeof(uint32_t));
m_records.push_back(StoredRecord::createShared(0, data1)); // fine
m_records.push_back(StoredRecord::createShared(1, data2)); // fine

// crashes with "malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)"
// at mem(new unsigned char[SIZEMACRO(_mem)])
m_records.push_back(StoredRecord::createShared(2, data3));
```

However, if I decrease `c = 1900` everything is fine. With a, b or c above ~1950, it crashes with the `malloc invalid size` when run with GDB or run normaly.
I've also run my code with valgrind, **there no crash happens** and it dosn't even complain about that `new unsigned char`. I already double-checked the `SIZEMACRO()` and it evaluates fine to 1800, 1900 and 2000. 
What puzzles me is the error-message "invalid size". Why can't I malloc more then ~1950 bytes here?

Comment: The `SIZEMACRO` may contain Undefined Behaviour.  Please include it in the question.

Comment: @RichardCritten its not very complicated: `#define SIZEMACRO(mem) *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(mem);` Ive run tests in an for-loop up to 32k (max possible size), macro does what it should.

Comment: Technically exactly the `*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>` on a pointer of `char` is undefined behavior.. What is `StoredBIR`? What is `m_records`? Are you missing `#include <memory>`?

Comment: I don't assume it changes anything, but try doing `memcpy` back into a `uint32_t` variable instead of `reinterpret_cast` (because the latter is indeed UB). E.g. like https://godbolt.org/z/FK5mbD

Comment: You could also inspect the assembly listing to see what exactly is passed to the failing `malloc` call. If there is UB anywhere, then unit-testing `SIZEMACRO` tells you nothing.

Comment: The "invalid size" that the message refers to is not your size argument but an internal "chunk size" used by the memory manager, which has an unexpected value. Since that is invalid, you must have a memory corruption bug somewhere in your code. Unfortunately for you, it could almost be anywhere.

Comment: @MaxLanghof already done it with copying, no changes. Also used `uint32_t rs = SIZEMACRO(mem)` and did a `printf("%ui\n");` with it. Everything fine over there. The error happens even after a correct value read in the output of printf and `new unsigned char[rs]`.

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you for pointing out that this is UB, didn't know that! `StoredBIR` was an unlucky C&P error, fixed it. `m_records` is stated in the question: its a class member of the class calling that code (`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<StoredRecord>> m_records`)

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you! finally something I can work with. Can I somehow find where the malloc wants to allocate the data so I can check the surrounding memory and search the bad code?

Comment: @bam That would provide no information whatsoever. You need to study your own code very carefully until you find the problem. I would start with looking for uninitialised variables and other potential uses of invalid objects.